# Match a pattern only once

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, find-occurrences

I have a string

```
foo-bar-bat.bla
```

I wish to match only `foo`

My flawed pattern matches both `foo` and `bar`

```
\w+(?=-.*\.bla)
```

How do I discard `bar`? Or maybe even better, how could I stop matching stuff after `foo`?

Comment: You can stop matching after the first match (either with `Matcher` or `replaceFirst`), or do I miss anything?

Comment: My comment earlier was about Java, but I think there are equivalent construct in other languages to stop at first match. The only case that my comment does not apply is when you are using some kind of tool. But there are always trick to work-around, if you give more example and context.

Comment: What is the relation between foo and bar? Does bar need to be present?

Comment: How much does your input string vary? Is it always going to be three chars, dash, three chars, dash, three chars, dot, 3 chars?

Comment: Yes, it's always going to have the same format. I tried testing Hugo's regex (http://www.pythonregex.com) by prepending a caret:  ^\w+(?=-.*\.bla) Seems like that should work but in pythonregex.com it produced no results. I used the following test data: asf.asf-asf.bla  bla-bla-boo.bla  foo-bar-bat.bla  Without the caret the test produces:                   >>> regex.findall(string)
[u'asf', u'bla', u'bla', u'foo', u'bar']

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the following pattern (as long as your strings are always formatted the way you said) :

```
^\w+(?=-.*\.bla)
```

[image: Regular expression image]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/EkIvhuQ8TmetiL5q)

The `^` sign matches the beginning of the string. And thus will take the very first match of the string.

*The `?=` is meant to make sure the group following is not captured but is present.*

Comment: I am not sure about the intention, but it will not match anything in the case `[foo]bar-r.bla`, while the regex in the question will match the example I give.

Comment: @nhahtdh That's is true but based on the only example we have what I said would work. Though as you said it depends of the case.

Comment: This pattern works on my python 2.7 web framework. Maybe I'm using www.pythonregex.com incorrectly but for some reason I can't get any results when I prepend a caret.

Comment: Well, the caret is a pretty standard character. Maybe the python version is too old on the site though

Answer (score 0):

```
^[^-]+
```

The starting `^` means to start matching from the beginning of the string. The charactergroup `[^-]` means to search for anything that is not a dash. The `+` means that the charactergroup should be match a character one or multiple times.

Comment: This is too permissive. The regex in the question only searches for word character `\w` (`[A-Za-z0-9_]`), while you allow all sort of character to be matched.

Comment: @mrhobo with that case you don't match the file extension

Comment: who said anything about file extensions?

Comment: @mrhobo well by his example he matches specially the `\.bla`

Comment: @HugoDozois fine extensions that is :)

Answer (score 0):

The ".*" part of your expression matches "bar."

`^\w+(?=-.*)`

This expression reads as "At the start of a string, at least one character followed by (but not includeded in the match) a DASH followed by anything"

```
^ \w+ (?=-.*)
|  |    |
|  |   matches "-bar-bat.bla"
|  matches "foo"
start of string
```

Comment: Notice, that the explanation-example ignores spaces.